Repeated execution of PL/pgSQL function triggers error "could not open relation with OID ..."
I've hit a snag with the following PL/pgSQL function I wrote:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION swipl_rpc(IN json_in JSONB, OUT json_out JSONB)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $code_block$
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (json_tmp JSONB);
EXECUTE format($bash$ COPY tmp FROM PROGRAM 'ggp-json ''%s''' $bash$, json_in);
SELECT json_tmp FROM tmp INTO json_out;
DROP TABLE tmp;
END;
$code_block$;

It works fine if the returned JSON is a couple of thousand characters long. But a 28618 byte JSON return string resulted in:

ERROR:  could not open relation with OID 2948131


It seems to be related to the input string size, but I'm a bit in the dark here.

About the reported error
Not related to the length of the input string. The problem was with saved query plans. Not for the COPY command but for the subsequent SELECT & DELETE.
PL/pgSQL can save query plans for nested SQL statements. Since the function body of a PL/pgSQL function is stored as plain string, no dependencies are registered. If you drop and recreate a table used in a saved plan, that can lead to the error message you reported. See:

LANGUAGE SQL vs LANGUAGE plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions

Better function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.swipl_rpc(IN json_in jsonb, OUT json_out jsonb)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT AS
$func$
BEGIN
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS swipl_rpc_tmp (json_tmp jsonb);

   EXECUTE format('COPY pg_temp.swipl_rpc_tmp FROM PROGRAM %L;
                   SELECT json_tmp FROM pg_temp.swipl_rpc_tmp;'
                , 'ggp-json ' || quote_literal(json_in))
   INTO json_out;

   EXECUTE 'DELETE FROM pg_temp.swipl_rpc_tmp';
END
$func$;

A temporary table is cheaper and more appropriate for your purpose.
Plus, your current solution is open to SQL injection.
The core problem in your question is solved by executing commands involving the (temporary) table dynamically (with EXECUTE), which never uses saved query plans. So dropping and re-creating the table can't invalidate saved plans.
EXECUTE can take multiple SQL statements at once. Put the SELECT command right after COPY. The INTO clause moves from SELECT to the EXECUTE command, SELECT must be the final command.
(Since I don't drop the temp table, the reported error should not normally happen any more anyway.)
Use a more specific table name, so that conflicts are unlikely. And schema-qualify explicitly, so it can't be resolved to another table of the same name  in the search path by accident if the temp table is missing (pg_temp.swipl_rpc_tmp). Both good practice.
The temp table only ever has a single row, so use DELETE without WHERE. Cheaper.
SQL injection?
There are 4 levels of nested quoting in this piece of code:

The literal representing the JSON value json_in must be quoted like any string. (Escaping any nested single quotes!)

Said string literal is argument to the program ggp-json, and the two are nested in single quotes within the COPY command.

The COPY command, plus the subsequent SELECT form a string as argument to EXECUTE.

The EXECUTE command is nested in the function body of the PL/pgSQL function - another quoted string.


Your solution misses level 1 and pastes json_in with the format specifier %s. Any nested single quotes are not escaped and trigger an error (in the best case) or can be abused for SQL injection (in the worst case).
I fixed that by first quoting json_in with quote_literal(). Then concatenate with your program name ggp-json and quote for the next level by using the format specifier %L to format().
See:

SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries
Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL

Different approach?
(Ab-)using COPY to execute an external program is only a workaround. A proper C function would be (much) more efficient and could return directly without a (temp) staging table.
Or a function with PL/Perl or PL/Python? (If you have one of those installed.) See:

Execute system commands in PostgreSQL


The problem is that when that function is compiled (on first use) the reference to table tmp is compiled too (OID 2948131). The second time you call it (with the same session) it will create a new temporary table for you but the compiled SELECT statement points still to the old table.
You have a number of options:

Use a different procedural language that doesn't compile its statements.
Avoid the use of temporary tables.
Use dynamic SQL (with EXECUTE) for all the statements involved with the temporary table.

I'd probably go with #3 if the function is really that short.

Removing TEMPORARY made no difference. It works fine if I manually the the steps between BEGIN ... END; replacing the string generated by EXECUTE format(...) with the desired command, but I can't get the function to work once the returned JSON gets slightly large.

@joeblog: For the record, the table being temporary is not the problem per se. Dropping and recreating the table (temporary or not) between executions conflicts with saved query plans.

I resolved the problem by first creating a "permanent" table
CREATE TABLE copy_jsonb (json_response JSONB);

And then rewrote the function to use that permanent table rather than create and delete a temporary table:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION swipl_rpc(IN json_in JSONB, OUT json_out JSONB)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $code_block$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format($bash$ COPY copy_jsonb FROM PROGRAM 'ggp-json ''%s''' $bash$, json_in);
SELECT json_response FROM copy_jsonb INTO json_out;
DELETE FROM copy_jsonb WHERE json_response = json_out;
END;
$code_block$;

Now the function no longer gives the dreaded could not open relation with OID error.
